# Quelle serait une façon plus élégante (en employant d’autres mots) d’exprimer la phrase citée dans les détails?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation-idiomatique, formulation

En temps de pandémie, certains ont pris la voie de l’amaigrissement, d’autres ont pris la voie de l’embonpoint.
C’est vraiment mal exprimé, c’est pourquoi je cherche une autre façon de rendre corps à l’expression de ma pensée en recourant à d’autres termes et à d’autres expressions.

Comment: — « La pandémie a conduit certains aux rondeurs d'autres à la maigreur. » — « Qu'elles soient devenues maigres ou enveloppées, ces personnes ont souffert de la pandémie ».

Comment: @Thélée_Lavoie — Aucun problème, c'est votre liberté et votre choix :-)

Comment: @Personne Merci !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Le langage imagé est peut-être ce qu'il y a de plus propice pour une telle idée, selon le  contexte, mais un langage littéral peu avoir la préférence.

- La pandémie a vu certains glisser sur la pente de l'amaigrissement et d'autres sur celle de l'embonpoint.
- En ces temps de pandémie certains  n'ont pas pu se garder de l'amaigrissement cependant que d'autres se sont abandonnés à l'embonpoint.
- Il aura fallu la pandémie à certains  pour se résigner à l'amaigrissement, et à d'autres pour se laisser aller à prendre de l'embonpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Pandémie rime pour certains avec boulimie, mais pour d'autres avec anorexie.

Answer (score 0):

Avec la préposition [pendant](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pendant#Pr%C3%A9position), on a certainement l'idée de l'intervalle durant laquelle le poids a été gagné/perdu, de sorte qu'on peut simplifier toute cette idée de progression (la [*voie*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/voie), [*a*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/a-)maigrisse[*ment*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/-ment)) et employer un pronom pour ne pas répéter (*poids, en*) :

> Pendant la pandémie, certains ont perdu du poids alors que d'autres en
> ont gagné.

On peut aussi faire référence à un seul état, au gain ou à la perte de poids, avec *(le) [contraire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/contraire#Nom_commun)* (« ...alors que pour d'autres ça semble être le contraire »). On peut aussi penser à des termes comme *régime*, *excès*, *jeûne*, ou à une allusion avec une expression et son antonyme comme *faire [bonne](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_bonne_ch%C3%A8re)/[petite](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/faire_petite_ch%C3%A8re) chère*.

Answer (score 0):

> [La pandémie a conduit certains aux rondeurs d'autres à la maigreur.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44289/quelle-serait-une-fa%C3%A7on-plus-%C3%A9l%C3%A9gante-en-employant-d-autres-mots-d-exprimer-la#comment90138_44289)
> [Qu'elles soient devenues maigres ou enveloppées, ces personnes ont
> souffert de la pandémie.](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/44289/quelle-serait-une-fa%C3%A7on-plus-%C3%A9l%C3%A9gante-en-employant-d-autres-mots-d-exprimer-la#comment90138_44289)